# JQuery alternative to .animate?

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery script to keep my footer always at the bottom of the browser no matter what.

The issue is it uses "Animate" to force it to move down or up which shows a footer scrolling from the top to the bottom every time a page loads. Like a flying footer bar.

I was wondering if there is an alternative from "Animate" to just force it to show up at the bottom and now a scrolling effects which shows it dragging down?

Snippet of code here, the ".animate" is what i need an alternative for i believe.

```
 $(window).bind("load", function() { 

   var footerHeight = 0,
       footerTop = 0,
       $footer = $("#Footer");

   positionFooter();

   function positionFooter() {

            footerHeight = $footer.height();
            footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";


           if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height() + 150) {
               $footer.css({
                    position: "absolute"
               }).stop().animate({
                    top: footerTop
               })
           } else {
               $footer.css({
                    position: "static"
               })
           }

   }

   $(window)
           .scroll(positionFooter)
           .resize(positionFooter)
```

});

Comment: Can't you just use CSS for this?

Comment: CSS the content expands the footer, the footer becomes floating over the content. This works great, i just dont like the scrolling effect of the footer down to its potiions.

Comment: sorry, i couldnt mark it as answered by myself since it takes 2 days, so i didn't want people to keep coming and trying to figure it out. what should i do in the future if i answer my own question before 2 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to specify the delay on ".animate" to "0". Below is the updated code.

```
  if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height() + 150) {
               $footer.css({
                    position: "absolute"
               }).stop().animate({
                    top: footerTop
               }, 0)
           } else {
               $footer.css({
                    position: "static"
               })
           }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply place the footer in a fixed position at the bottom of the screen -

```css
#footer { position:fixed; bottom:0px }
```

Comment: i've spent hours using CSS for what i want to keep the footer at the bottom and always have issues with content overflowing it or other issues on the site. This method works, i just want the JQuery to have the footer simply appear and not scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: If you wrap your main content you can give it a `magin-bottom` equal to the `height` of the footer - that way your content will not go below the footer...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need animation so go for CSS solution. As @lix mentioned.

```
#footer { position:fixed; bottom:0px }
```

On the other hand, in case of having animations, there are two ways:

1. JS solution
2. CSS3 transition propertiy.

   ```
   #footer { 
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0px;

      -webkit-transition: 3s linear 1s;
      -moz-transition: 3s linear 15s;
      -o-transition: 3s linear 1s;
      -ms-transition: 3s linear 1s;
      transition: 3s linear 1s;
   }
   ```